# How do I made sure a RecordToSample correctly writes to a Sample in Java Beads?

Tags: java, audio, audio-recording

I'm using the [Beads Project](http://www.beadsproject.net/) audio library for Java. I'm trying to modify the 7th tutorial file to record its sound in non-realtime mode and write the sound to a file. I'm doing so by using the `RecordToSample` class. However, when I try to write the sample to a file, it doesn't look like the RecordToSample has actually written any data to the sample - the file that's written is just a few seconds of silence, based on the length of the buffer I initialized the sample with, not the length of the recording.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Lesson07_RecordToSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final AudioContext ac;

        ac = new AudioContext();
        /*
         * I added this code
         */
        final Sample sample = new Sample(10000D);
        final RecordToSample recorder = new RecordToSample(ac, sample);


        Clock clock = new Clock(ac, 700);
        clock.addMessageListener(
                  //this is the on-the-fly bead
                  new Bead() {
                       // snip

                      /*
                       * I added this code
                       */
                       if(c.getCount() == 70) {
                           Sample sample = recorder.getSample();
                           try {
                               sample.write("audio/song.wav", AudioFileType.WAV);
                           } catch (IOException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                           ac.stop();
                       }
                   }
                 }
        );
    ac.out.addDependent(clock);
    /*
     * I changed this line
     */
    ac.runNonRealTime();

    }

    public static float random(double x) {
        return (float)(Math.random() * x);
    }
}
```

This creates a new file at audio/song.wav, but this file just contains 10 seconds of silence. It looks to me that the recorder isn't actually changing any of the data in the sample, and when the sample is written, it just uses the 10000 ms of empty data I initialized it with.

I've been looking through the Beads library's docs, and it doesn't look like there are any methods to the RecordToSample class that force the RecordToSample to push its data into its Sample. What is the proper way to make sure that the data I'm recording with the RecordToSample is correctly written to the Sample? Can you please provide a short code example?

Comment: I'm also asking for help on the Beads project Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beadsproject/4CThflEtXFY

Comment: There's now a tutorial in the Beads project showing how to use `RecordToSample`: https://github.com/orsjb/beads/blob/master/packages/Beads/beads_tutorial/Lesson09_RecordToSample.java